# Bonobo git server returns item was not found

Tags: git, bonobo

I've installed the bonobo git server on Windows 2012 and IIS 8. I've followed all the installation steps. I've created an empty repository. Then on my computer I have :

1. created an empty folder
2. Add a file to the folder
3. executed git init
4. git add -A
5. git commit
6. git remote add origin giturl
7. git push origin admin

but git returns fatal: repository ... not found

I've tried with git URL and personal URL, also tried allowing anonymous push to the repository but nothing works.
In the same machine, I've had no any problems when working against GitHub.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of Bonobo doesn't allow you to create a repo just by pushing at a non-existent one.  That's an option ("Allow push to create repositories") you have to turn on in settings via the web interface.

Comment: The repository already exists I've created on the bonobo web interface before trying to push any changes. nonetheless, I've also tried with the options: "Allow user repository creation" and  "Allow push to create repositories" both checked without any success.

Comment: If you've created the repo on the web interface, you should clone it to your client machine, not init a new one on the client.